# Equal sign is missing

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following code is failing with `ORA-00927: missing equal sign`:

```
if (countExceed > 0) then 
    quer :=
        'Update UID_RM_HIERARCHY I
            SET I.REVIEWER_UID IN
            (
                SELECT L.REVIEWER_UID
                  FROM UID_RM_HIERARCHY L
                 WHERE L.UNIQUE_ID  in (' || p_ID_list || ')
            )
      WHERE I.REVIEWER_UID in('||p_ID_list||')
        AND I.isdeleted=0';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE quer;
```

What should I change to fix it?

Comment: plsql block in stored procedure

Comment: It should be `update x set y = z`. You have `IN` where the equal sign should be.

Comment: Which will, I bet, lead to `TOO-MANY-ROWS`, @William. Not that your suggestion is wrong, but I presume that the OP used `in` trying to avoid it. Query uses `L.UNIQUE_ID` which promises uniqueness, but - it is compared to a `P_ID_LIST` which suggests just the opposite (unless list contains a single ID, and then there shouldn't be `in` but `=`). That's where my fears come from.

Comment: Agreed there are a bunch of other things wrong with the code. I was just commenting on the error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/230471/william-robertson Please can you give me example like this

Comment: i have separated this big query in parts like

Comment: if (countExceed > 0) then 
vSQL :='SELECT L.REVIEWER_UID FROM UID_RM_HIERARCHY L WHERE L.UNIQUE_ID  in('||p_ID_list||')';execute immediate vSQL into vResult;
            
                quer :='UPDATE UID_RM_HIERARCHY I SET I.REVIEWER_UID ='''||vResult||''' and I.isdeleted=0';
                    
                     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  quer ; 
                    end if;

Comment: but got new error command is not properly ended

Comment: Please add code to your question and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code run you could do this:

```
if (countExceed > 0) then 
    quer :=
        'Update UID_RM_HIERARCHY I
            SET I.REVIEWER_UID = -- place always a "=" and no "IN"
            (
                SELECT L.REVIEWER_UID
                  FROM UID_RM_HIERARCHY L
                 WHERE L.UNIQUE_ID  in (' || p_ID_list || ')
                   AND ROWNUM = 1 -- This query has to give you a single value! Because of this we only select the first value (properbly wrong?!)
            )
      WHERE I.REVIEWER_UID in('||p_ID_list||')
        AND I.isdeleted=0';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE quer;
```

But i strongly suggest reading some tutorials. Or clearly explain what you're doing. I'm still not sure what you're doing with those `p_ID_list` or what it contains.

For further help you should tell us:

- What are your tables?
- What do they contain?
- What does p_ID_list contain?
- What are you going to do with the list step-by-step?